# My object which throw flame does not appearing during rendering?

Tags: blender-internal-render-engine, blend-files

Dear experts my object which project flames on wall does not appearing during rendering I do not know why 
things I have done 
*all layers are in  unrestrict mode

thanks in advance :)
file is attached      Here is the link for file

https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B6EziauliLnTQ3hGWGlLcUJQSms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: You need to use a volumetric material on the domain object utilizing the voxel data from the smoke sim.  Since I am not a BI expert I will let someone else write a full answer, unless you are open to using Cycles?

Answer (score 1):

For the issue of the flame not appearing during render, there are two things you might want to consider that caught my eye upon looking at your scene.

First, is the material. You haven't created or assigned a material to the particles for your flow object- 'Plane'. Create a material for your flame, and assign it in the render tab> materials drop down (highlighted in yellow)

Second, is the emitter type to display(highlighted in red). Currently it is set to none. Select another option (*halo* works well for fire), and you will see your flame in the final render.

[image]